# iPhone UIWebView Bug

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am getting this error message in the console, while i am trying to load a html page in UIWebView ?

"void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: UITrackingRunLoopMode
If you were not using the touch screen for this entire interval (which can prolong this wait), please file a bug."

Any reason for it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is necessarily your problem, but I have received the same message when a piece of Javascript takes too long to execute. Do you know if the webpage you are loading is doing any heavy javascript on load?

In my case I was testing if you could use prompt() in a UIWebView - which worked, but gave the error you mentioned if I took more than 10 seconds to dismiss the popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you only see this error when you put a breakpoint in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` I don't think that this is a problem.

On the other hand, if you see it when your code is running normally then it *is* a problem. You may need to break out the parsing of the XML file into a separate thread or, at least, decouple it from the web view.