# UIWebView shows error message

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am getting this error message in the console, while I am trying to load a HTML page in `UIWebView`?

"void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: UITrackingRunLoopMode If you were not using the touch screen for this entire interval (which can prolong this wait), please file a bug.". When I am debugging my code and wait wait for several second before clicking continue at this method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // finished loading, hide the activity indicator in the status bar
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:mPath];
}
```

Comment: Please upvote other questions rather than opening new, duplicate ones (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593956/iphone-uiwebview-bug/1721676#1721676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you all you need to know: that you are taking too long to return from a delegate method.

If you're fetching stuff from the internet, that's your problem right there. Fatal error, do not resuscitate. Re-think your app structure.

Otherwise, you might need to make your xml parsing more efficient, because it's taking too long.